# How probability changes as possible options are eliminated - Video game example

Tags: probability

I don't have much of a math background, but wanted confirmation of a probability problem I've come across, for a free fan website I'm working on.

**Edit**: The reason I ask is because I've seen some videos on the Monty Hall Problem / Bertrand's Box & I want to make sure I'm not tricking myself into believing something that doesn't actually logically follow. I don't think either applies here, as the options are just being randomly eliminated, with no additional information added; but I wanted to make sure.

In the game "Animal Crossing: New Horizons" there is a "stock market" of sorts. There's a period where you can buy into the market, every Sunday. Then, each week, the market follows one of 4 broad patterns; Random, Large Spike, Decreasing, or Small Spike. The probability of each is dependent on the previous week's pattern. In the graphic below, the left-hand column is the previous week's pattern (determined by playing, and explained below) and the columns represent the odds for the new pattern, the following week:

[image: Animal Crossing weekly pattern matrix]

After a broad pattern is determined by the game, a "sub-pattern" is then generated based on rules set by the parent pattern. For instance, a "Decreasing" pattern will drop day-by-day. A Small Spike will build to a peak and then drop slightly over the course of 5 days, but when this happens during the week is random, but equally likely. The player has no knowledge of what the game has determined at the start of the week, beyond being aware of the above probability matrix (assuming they worked out their previous week's pattern).

At 12 different "buying points" during the week, a new market "purchase price" is successively revealed. It's by observing these values that we can figure out the pattern-- however, the pattern may not be evident at first, as they share similarities. For example, *all* patterns have a buying period where the price is worse than the purchase price; the ranges for *how much lower* vary, and with overlap between each sub-pattern. Some results give a very clear outcome of eliminating possible patterns: I.e. if a price is ever higher than the buying price then it can't be the consistently "Decreasing" pattern, etc. The goal is to as quickly as possible, determine the pattern & sell for that weeks' maximum possible profit.

As a clearer example, from my site, assuming a purchase price of 100 and a buying price of 65 at the first buying period, these are the remaining possibilities for each "Small Spike sub-patterns" across the remaining 11 buying points, (**$** represents the peak of the spike, a **+** is a high value, and a **-** is a low value). The fact that Monday, period-1 is a low value, has eliminated one of the original eight possibilities (a peak on Tuesday afternoon), leaving seven remaining:

[image: Reduced Small Spike Possibility Table]

With no additional information, at the start of the week: there are 56 different possible "Random" sub-patterns, 7 "Large Spike" sub-patterns, 1 "Decreasing" sub-pattern, and 8 "Small Spike" sub-patterns.

I want to show to the user, as the week progresses & new "buying point" values are revealed, how the likelihood of the patterns is changing. With all that being said, my question is: *Is the following logic correct?*

Assuming the previous week was "Random", that means each "Random" sub-pattern at the outset has an equal
`1/56 * 20%` chance of occurring, each large spike sub-pattern `1/7 * 30%`, etc. Once the first value is revealed, it may eliminate some of these possibilities. If half of the "Random" sub-patterns are deemed no longer possible, and none of the other sub-patterns are affected, then the odds that it's "Random" will have dropped from the original "20%" chance of occurring. Since those 28 options accounted for 10% of the original probabilities, then I need to scale each remaining option, by dividing them by `0.9`. I.e. the remaining "Random" chance is: `28 * 1/56 * 20% / 0.9 == 11.11%`, and likewise the total odds for Large Spike is now `30% / 0.9 == 33.33%`, and this follows for Small Spike and Decreasing as well.

Is this logic correct, and does it extend, in general, to how the probabilities will change as any number of possibilities are eliminated? This seems to make sense from what I remember of probability trees & intuitively looking at the numbers.

For those curious: [here's the full google doc these figures are based on](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bSVNpOnH_dKxkAGr718-iqh8s8Z0qQ54L-0mD-lbrXo/edit#heading=h.3idxbkvj9ziz).

Comment: It was only a matter of time before ACNH left a footprint in our community I suppose